# mysql query that only returns rows that were added past a certain time using

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

If I have a table that has a TIMESTAMP column, and I want to retrieve only the rows that were added after a php variable that was set by $time=strtotime("now") was created, how would I format the query syntax?

$q= "SELECT * FROM `webchat_lines` WHERE `author` = 'someone' ***{between $time and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP}*** ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 20";

Comment: +1 for strtotime('now'). That's a good trick, didn't realise it could do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$q = "SELECT *
      FROM webchat_lines
      WHERE author='someone'
        AND timestamp BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME($time) AND NOW()
      ORDER BY id DESC
      LIMIT 20";
```

This uses [`FROM_UNIXTIME($time)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) to convert the `strtotime` output (seconds since 1970-xx-xx etc) to a date so it can be compared to your timestamp column. `NOW()` is an alias for `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`.

Answer (score 1):

$q= "SELECT * FROM webchat_lines WHERE author = 'someone' AND timestamp_colum BETWEEN '$time' AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Comment: awesome, so: $time instantiated by strtotime("now") will be in the correct format?

Comment: no that won't work, see my answer. strtotime of now will return a unix time stamp - http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$q= "SELECT * FROM webchat_lines WHERE author = 'someone' AND timestamp between $time and NOW() ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20"
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers so far have failed to mention that time needs to be formatted as a MYSQL.

### Convert time to a MYSQL DATETIME string

```
$time = date_format(time(), 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

### Run the SQL

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM webchat_lines 
        WHERE author = 'someone' AND 
              timestamp BETWEEN '$time' AND NOW() 
        ORDER BY id DESC 
        LIMIT 20";
```

We are using the between operator: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between
and using date format: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Date format for mysql is YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss